# Eclipse Plugin Dev: How to use new Rich Text Hovers (since 3.4)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've implemented plain text hovers in my plugin with ITextHover. And now I want to use new eclipse 3.4 feature - Rich text hovers with text styles, images and actions.But I can't find articles/examples about it. What interfaces should I use and where?
I found ITextHoverExtension2 interface, but can't find how to create hover objects (what class should they be?) and what interface should catch them?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the OP is still interested, but for the record: What I wrote previously was half-right and more than three-quarters wrong (and yes, I can do math :-)  I've written a [blog post](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2009/05/eclipse-rich-hovers-redux/) that, I hope, does a better job in covering this subject.

(If you're frowning at this self-promotion, you can smile at the knowledge that this update isn't likely to draw many readers.)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this. The main problem is what to return. Also I feel there should be class for presenting returned info. And I pray there is some standard presenter for html with actions for links. Just like in problem resolving popup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dan. For a long time I thought this question is unanswered... (you know, edits are not highlighted in questions list).  
One more please, is there a HoverControl that can contain hyperlincs, that can run actions (or better, handlers, since Eclipse movin' that way)?

Comment: I haven't been playing in Eclipse as much lately, so my knowledge is a bit rusty now.

My guess is that it's possible, since I the blog post I wrote shows that you can put just about anything inside a hover control. I don't know how much of the work would be covered by existing Eclispe APIs, though.

Now that Galileo's out, I may revisit this area sometime. If I find anything more, I'll drop a note here.